# How can i get the folders name inside of MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I need to get the folder names in MVC project. I will upload to these folders and then i will take from these folders. I havent tried before,colud you help me? I put the some pictures contains controller and view codes and SS.

**controller & view ;**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvrYq.png

**and UI ;**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzeZg.png

Comment: What is the error? Did you tried it? Its just read a folder and list all the files in it. Try it and ask for errors

Comment: 1. Your code needs to be in the question (not links to images of it). 2. What do you mean _get the folder names_?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want the name of images?

```
Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/yourPath"), "*.jpg").Select(r => r.Split('\\').Last().Replace(".jpg", string.Empty));
```